# Ensure ingress rule creation

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, fabric8

My problem: i create ingress rule via kubernetes-client:

```java
try (InputStream is = IOUtils.toInputStream(crd, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {            
    client.load(is).inNamespace(namespaceName).createOrReplace();
}
```

Where `is` - yaml file with ingress rule like:

```yaml
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
    - host: {{host}}
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              service:
                name: {{service_name}}
                port:
                  number: 80
            path: /
            pathType: ImplementationSpecific
```

But in my task i need ensure that the rule is created, i need wait or check status in loop.
What is the best way to do it?

Thanx!

Answer (score 2):

I think you might be able to do it with `waitUntilCondition`:

```java
try (KubernetesClient client = new KubernetesClientBuilder().build()) {
  Ingress ingress = client.network().v1().ingresses()
      .load(IngressRuleWaitUntilCondition.class.getResourceAsStream("/ingress-rule.yml"))
      .get();

  client.resource(ingress)
      .inNamespace("default")
      .createOrReplace();

  client.network().v1()
      .ingresses()
      .inNamespace("default")
      .resource(ingress)
      .waitUntilCondition(i -> !i.getSpec().getRules().isEmpty(), 2, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
}
```

Comment: Yes, but we need to use `withName`, cause `inNamespace` can't work with `waitUntilCondition`.

Comment: @aarexer: Updated my answer  to use `resource()` from which name can be inferred. Could you please check if this works for you?